# jQuery this find не работает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, form

Я пытаюсь использовать $(this).find('.class').html('text'), но он не работает (Обратите внимание на комментарий).

```js
$(".form_send").submit(function() {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?route=information/contact/send',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.error) {
        $(this).find('.result').html(data.error); //Не работает
        $('.form_send .result').html(data.error); //Работает
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
      $('.form_send')[0].reset();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('error; ' + error);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="tg-themeform tg-contactusform form_send">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_subject" placeholder="Тема">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mask" name="user_phone" placeholder="Телефон">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="user_message" placeholder="Сообщение" class="tg-textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <button class="tg-btn" type="submit"><span>Отправить</span></button>
        <div class="result"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Ajax работает исправно. Ответ от сервера получаю правильный.

Comment: и что же тут странного ? оно и не должно работать так как вы хотите, ведь у функции `success` свой this, и он не является формой

Comment: Можете после var data сделать следующее: var that = this; И в переменной that у Вас будет this. А дальше используйте that. Это одно из возможных решений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```js
$.ajax({
    //Ваш код
    context: this,
    success: function(data) {
         // this ссылается на то, что Вы указали в context
    }
});
```